# i am having issue in selecting data using vb asp.net

Tags: vb.net

Hi i need to select all data from database and show it in vb asp.net Gridview, tried many codes but having problem in it

My Code So Far Is

```
  Dim Con As SqlConnection
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand

        Dim str As String = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='C:\Users\abc\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\Cinematickets\App_Data\moviedatabase.mdf';Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"

        Con = New SqlConnection(str)

        Con.Open()

        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM users", Con)

        Dim table As New DataTable()

        adapter.Fill(table)

        GridView1.DataSource = table

        Con.Close()
```

And HTML CODE is

```
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>
```

but not working.
Please try to make it better 
Thanks a lot 
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should call databind() method after datasource() method.

Comment: Yes Solved Thanks

Comment: happy to help you